# UITableViewController and safe area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am using a subclass of `UITableViewController` to back my very simple table view controller. Like so:

[image]
[image: FriendsViewController]
[image]

```
class FriendsViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = true

    }
}
```

However, the table view is covering the safe safe area. This is particularly obvious when i preview on iPhone X emulator.

[image]

I would expect to see something like this:

[image]

I tried using `tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea`, as per my code snippet above, but it doesn't do what the Apple documentation says it should:

> When the value of this property is true (the default), the table view adjusts the insets of the content view within each of its cells, headers, and footers on the leading and trailing sides to make the content fit within the safe area.

I am aware of alternative solutions without `UITableViewController`, but i specifically want to use it (it's very convenient) and would expect to be able to tune it such that it behaves properly and observes the safe area. It would defy belief, that Apple designed a broken component.

Anyway, none of the posts with similar questions helped, so hoping for a fresh start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’re seeing is normal and correct. The table view is the entire view of the view controller and covers the whole screen. It still works fine because the scrolling content is inset, so the user can scroll to see all parts of the table; the top of the table is inset down. So all is well.

If you really want the effect shown in your last screen shot, you’ll have to make the table view controller a child view controller of some other view controller. A typical interface is to wrap the table view controller  in a navigation controller so that the nav bar fills the top of the screen. Or you could manually use a container view / embed segue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. No, not really looking to change any default UITableViewController behaviour, so long as it is correct with respect to safe are. Moreover, i finally had enough brains to check for an example on official Apple site, and the table indeed flows all the way to the screen bottom under the home indicator (the short black line):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

But still, i don't understand. I thought the whole point of the safe area was to ensure nothing shows up there - no?

Comment: Not “nothing”. Subviews. But your table view is not a subview. All I can suggest is that you reread my answer. A view controller’s view, if this is not a child view controller, always occupies the whole screen. And that’s what you got when you decided to use a table view controller that isn’t a child. I told you two common ways to make it a child. Basically now I’ve repeated my whole answer as a comment.

Comment: I understood the points about embedding or placing in navigation controller. And like I said, not really looking to modify the default layout, as we’ve established it doesn’t violate safe area constraints.  What I don’t understand is why table view (or any other view controller’s “base” view, which occupies the whole screen) entering safe area at the bottom of the screen  is considered ok. I suppose it is because iOS “knows” to place it such that it doesn’t cover essential controls, like home or time/signal indicators. I.e. *under* those controls.

Comment: I have to say it a third time? A full screen view controller’s view occupies the full screen. That’s what you’ve got. The table view is not a subview. It is THE VIEW.